# Response assertion failing even though the document does contain the expected text

Tags: jmeter, assertion

I have a response assertion validating the 'Document (text)' of a response.

This is the assertion

[image: Assertion]

This is the failure
[image: Failure]

This is the response that the assertion is checking. As you can see I have directly copied 'Statutory Currency USD Total Tax (SC) 58.80' from the failing assertion and it is found in the response?!
[image: Response]

Other assertions are passing for this request.

[image]

Comment: can you show assertion configuration ? thanks

Comment: I've added that to the OP. As I've said, I have other patterns that are working fine in the same assertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice you can (maybe should) switch to using `Substring` instead of `Contains` which will fix your issue, because it doesn't use regex which have [reserved characters as `(`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)

> Contains - true if the text contains the regular expression pattern
>
> Substring - true if the text contains the pattern string (case-sensitive)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the '(' and ')' needed to be escaped using a '\'.

Answer (score 0):

You’re using document instead of Text response in Fields to test.

Document is usually reserved to asserting on pdf, excel, word document. it has an important cost in terms of performance and is not needed when asserting on text (html, json...)

Also you should favor substring instead of contains.